# Forward HTTP traffic with erlang

Tags: http, tcp, erlang, forward

I want to write a "smart" load balancer, with "smart" I mean that it should route different request on different servers and ports based on the URL.

As example `somehost.com/server1` should go to the server1 while `somehost.com/server3` should go to the server3.

However I don't want my load balancer to establish the connection with the client, make the requests to the backend server, and the return to the client.
The load balancer should be as much transparent as possible.

The request should arrive to the backend servers and then return immediately to the client, without the need to go through the load balancer.

How is this achievable ? Are there example in erlang ?

Comment: Why not just use an actual load balancer?

Comment: Accepting a TCP connection means you are pretty much stuck shipping traffic back and forth between client and your back end, you can't palm your TCP end point off to another server. You will have to accept the connection to get the URL and thereby implement your "smart" load balancing, the only way round that is to return a redirect, but that will fail your transparency requirement.

Comment: @SteveVinoski, it is more a curiosity/exercise, I would use a load balancer if it need to run in production.

Comment: @Michael, that is definitely right, however, there are software that does what I mean, an example is HAproxy, how is that implemented ?

Comment: @Siscia I'm not sure what answer you expect other than "it must work by accepting connections and making connections to back end servers  in order to service them based on its configuration". Such an implementation could be achieved in a variety of ways. Really, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Michael, I don't think it should accept a connection, it can simply read the package and send it wherever is needed, like a dns would do...

Comment: @Siscia DNS is UDP, UDP is a connectionless protocol, and a DNS request is contained within a single packet. A load balancer can receive it, and route it, with any possible level of intelligence, because all the request information is available. A TCP is stateful, the first thing that will happen between 2 end points is the three way hand shake before any data or request is even sent. There's not really generally any practical way for the load balancer to get the request and "smart" route it without accepting the connection.

Comment: @Michael, how you think then HAproxy in implemented ? And I am refering to this particular feature: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.7.html#3.3.10

Comment: @Siscia The only way around this gets into territory which is pretty nuts. A load balancer would have to plug into the kernel (using something like NFQUEUE and libnetfilter_queue with Linux say) and monitor the TCP packets, responding the elements of the three way hand shake in order to elicit the payload/request, then decide where to load balance to, replay the three way hand shake to the target back end, and then fall back to packet forwarding. This is not necessarily impossible, but seriously nuts stuff.

Comment: @Michael, not to mention that if you want to handle HTTP traffic in a kernel-filtering load balancer, you'll need to do stateful packet inspection, because the HTTP Host header won't be in the initial `SYN` packet, and might not be in the first _N_ packets either...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Yes, all of which has to be replayed to the back end server of choice once the request is obtained, in order to retrospectively stitch the TCP connection back together. It is possible, and doing it this way you can, with appropriate configuration of network routing implement DSR (Direct Server Return) so that for a mainly download protocol like HTTP the load balancer is doing very little of the grunt work then. So it has huge pay back, but it is nuts. Erlang is fairly irrelevant, and not a particularly useful tool, for this sort of thing however. C is the language of choice.